# Transition camera to another position gradually?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I want to change the camera distance when the character becomes bigger. However I don't want it to happen immediatelly but to have the camera move over a second or two to the position.

How can I  transition the camera to the specific position over the lapse of one second? Is there a way to ease-in, ease-out the transition?

```
    Vector3 position = new Vector3 (0, 0, -transform.localScale.x);
    Camera.mainCamera.transform.localPosition = position;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly setting the position of the camera every time, you can declare a public Vector3 to use as a target. Then in your Update function, which is called every frame, you can use `Camera.mainCamera.transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(Camera.mainCamera.transform.localPosition, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);`

This will move your camera towards the target position gradually, at most `speed * Time.deltaTime` units per frame. If you want to make sure that the transition takes one second, then you can set `speed` to the distance at the same time as changing the target position.